# Extract part of a string from an Active Directory variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm pulling the following variable from `Active Directory`:

```
Homeshare=\\<filer_number>\Homedir\MyUsername.
```

I need to extract "filer_number" and set it as a variable to use elsewhere in my `logon.bat` file.  For instance, set `filer# = %filer%`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Wht do you mean by "extrapolate?" "estimate or conclude (something) by extrapolating" or "extend (a graph, curve, or range of values) by inferring unknown values from trends in the known data?" - How? Please show examples.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It sounds like you might mean "extract" instead of "extrapolate".  Are you trying to determine a piece of information from a segment of the `Home` share variable?

Comment: ooops, Yes, that should be extract.

Comment: @GBilder: I totally reworded your question.  Please verify that it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "testvar=Homeshare=\Filer#\Homedir\MyUsername"
for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %%a IN ("%testvar%") DO (set "filerVariable=%%a")
echo %filerVariable%
pause
```

This works by splitting the string using the `\` sign as delimiter, and taking the 2nd token.

Comment: Major caution however - OP has included a space between the variable name and the `=`. Batch assignments are literal. OP's example would set a variable called "filer#*space*" not "filer#".

Comment: You're right, but he says he wants to extract 'Filer#', and there he used quotes and didn't use spaces, so my guess he simply used the spaces around the if because that's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, it is very similar to @Dennis van Gils' answer, but I have some notes below.

```
@echo off
set target=3
set homedirstring="\\Filer#\Homedir\MyUsername"
for /F "tokens=%target% delims=\" %%a in ("%homedirstring%") DO (set "newvar=%%a")
echo %target%:%newvar%
```

1. The target is the segment of the homedir variable after it is split at the `\` character.  In this instance, "Filer#" is the 3rd substring.  If you need to change it, just change the target value.
2. As @Magoo indicated in a comment, be sure you do not put spaces after the `=` operator when assigning values to variables.  If you do, this space will be included in the value.

Comment: Holy Smokes, You guys are frigging awesome!! thank you everyone for your help!!